# How to understand using fields of type Class in another class?

Tags: c#, oop

I study C# from a book called C# player's guide this book is good very simple but I found myself stuck at certain chapter which is completely frustrating to me the author wants me to write a tic tac toe
console program (I did that but with procedural programming ) the author solution is very frustrating and vague using many classes and using fields of type Class in another which is new to me here is the code
this is the full solution of the author http://starboundsoftware.com/books/c-sharp/try-it-out/tic-tac-toe
ill just write down the codes where my confusion lies, I will write 3 Classes under the same namespace

```
public class Board
{
    private State[,] state;
    public State NextTurn { get; private set; }

    public Board()
    {
        state = new State[3, 3];
        NextTurn = State.X;
    }

    public State GetState(Position position)
    {
        return state[position.Row, position.Column];
    }

    public bool SetState(Position position, State newState)
    {
        if (newState != NextTurn) return false;
        if (state[position.Row, position.Column] != State.Undecided) return false;

        state[position.Row, position.Column] = newState;
        SwitchNextTurn();
        return true;
    }

    private void SwitchNextTurn()
    {
        if (NextTurn == State.X) NextTurn = State.O;
        else NextTurn = State.X;
    }
}
public class Position
{
    public int Row { get; }
    public int Column { get; }

    public Position(int row, int column)
    {
        Row = row;
        Column = column;
    }
}
 public class Player
{
    public Position GetPosition(Board board)
    {
        int position = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Position desiredCoordinate = PositionForNumber(position);
        return desiredCoordinate;
    }

    private Position PositionForNumber(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 1: return new Position(2, 0); // Bottom Left
            case 2: return new Position(2, 1); // Bottom Middle 
            case 3: return new Position(2, 2); // Bottom Right
            case 4: return new Position(1, 0); // Middle Left
            case 5: return new Position(1, 1); // Middle Middle
            case 6: return new Position(1, 2); // Middle Right
            case 7: return new Position(0, 0); // Top Left
            case 8: return new Position(0, 1); // Top Middle
            case 9: return new Position(0, 2); // Top Right
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand most of the logic here what I don't understand is this line of code

public Position GetPosition(Board board)

I think the author used a method of the type Position which is a class I don't understand that and why did he use that also fields of type Class like in this example I am very frustrated searched the internet to see something like that and I did not find anything helpful please if this Question is long and frustrating at least give me something to help me THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're having trouble understanding the syntax itself, so I'll break it down into its constituent concepts (italics) which can be further researched by name. See also the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods).

```
public Position GetPosition(Board board)
```

This declares a *method* named `GetPosition` (within the `Player` *class*):

- `public` is a C# language *keyword* used to tell the compiler that this method should be accessible from outside the class (i.e. given a Player object, anyone will be able to call `GetPosition` on it). Other *access modifier* keywords that could be used are `private`, `protected`, or even none at all (the default is private).
- `Position` is the *type* that `GetPosition` is declared to return (it must therefore return only object instances of that type, or of a derived type).
- In parentheses is the *parameter list* of the method. Parameter declarations in this list are separated by commas (`,`), but here there is only one parameter.
- The first (and only) parameter is declared to be of type `Board`. This means only object instances of that type (or of a derived type) can be passed as the first *argument* to this method when calling it.
- The first (and only) parameter is named `board`. The name can be arbitrary, but is used within the method's code to refer to the `Board` object instance that was *passed in* as an argument by the caller.

Comment: thank you for the reply it cleared a bit of confusion but still did not get the full picture gonna get through the full solution hope I don't give up